# Alternate Triassic dinosauriods

Tags: evolution, alternate-reality, dinosaurs

In a hypothetical alternate Earth where the Triassic extinction didn't occur, I envision dinosaurs taking to the trees to avoid the massive crocodile species that were prolific at that time (sorry for not having the exact taxonomy names). This leads to dinosaurs becoming combos of primates and hoatzins (Amazonian birds with claws on their wings). But then the Cretaceous extinction still happens and the crocodiles go mostly extinct. The dinosaurs return to the ground and since some are so much like our primate ancestors, they mimic our evolution into humanoid forms. Is this too much of a stretch?

Comment: You do know that birds do exist... and they are dinosaurs who took to the trees. (And there are many species of birds with claws on the fingers of their forelimbs, including ducks, geese and swans...)

Comment: Before creating a tag, asks yourself if it is really needed. What are we supposed to do with a [tag:plausibly] tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could happen. We came from reptiles and before that from fish.

Your mechanism for it happening is only a partial explanation though. These things take millions of happenstances to occur, but obviously can and have occurred.

The main flaw is getting them into the trees, some might (we have tree kangaroos), some were probably already in the trees, but most wouldn't, they'd just die off.

Not a huge problem for a story though, you just need to give some broad strokes and leave the rest to imagination.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this too much of a stretch?

Yes.

First reason: taking up to the tree to avoid the massive crocs roaming the ground is just one possible solution to the environmental pressure.

Having all the species going in that direction is rather implausible:

1. the trees would become pretty crowded
2. the crocs would adapt to climb trees if that would be the only way to ensure their meal.

Second reason: the mammal progenitor wasn't a specialized tree dweller, but an opportunistic ground dweller. Evolution-wise it's easy to specialize from an all round plan, going back from a specialized to a more all purpose it's more difficult. You are doing that.

Comment: I didn't mean all of them, just the most relevant